# WordPress horizontal scaling: how to share files across servers?

Tags: wordpress, docker, cloud, scaling, horizontal-scaling

So in a project i'm working on i'm trying to horizontally scale wordpress, my actual stack idea is :

- HA Proxy as a load balancer
- 3 webservers behind the load balancer running Nginx/ PHP7
- 1 Redis Server
- 1 or more MySql servers to make sure everything is ok for high availability

The issue comes to my mind when I think about file uploads, if a user tries to upload a picture to wordpress, the picture will be available only in the Nginx/PHP VPS the loadbalancer gave him.

My question would be something like :
How can I centralize all uploads ? Like using a "shared" wp-content folder ... I've read about GlusterFS and Ceph, will these be usefull ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than solve this strictly at the backend, I'd suggest you first consider something like CloudFlare in front of your WordPress site. You could setup caching on the upload directory... You're going to get enormous horizontal scalability out of that. And it's basically free and pretty easy to setup. We've got CloudFlare in front of a site serving over 500,000 page views a day and you'd be shocked at how light the load is on that server.

Beyond that, if you do put a load balancer up in front of your site, you should be able to have it route traffic from the same user to the same backend node, so it should be consistent for that user for the duration of their browser session. That'll give you time for a file synchronization tool of some kind to keep all of your balanced nodes in sync. You might look at https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison for this.